# Having Problems with MergeSort

Tags: python, sorting, merge

```
def merge(L, start_index, sublist_size):
    """
    Merge two sublists of a list L

    Parameters:
    L - the list
    start_index - the index of the first element to be merged
    sublist_size - the size of the chunks to be merged

    Left chunk: L[start_index] to L[start_index + sublist_size - 1]
    Right chunk: L[start_index + sublist_size] to L[start_index + 2 * sublist_size - 1]
    """

    index_left = start_index
    left_stop_index = start_index + sublist_size
    index_right = start_index + sublist_size
    right_stop_index = min(start_index + 2 * sublist_size,
                           len(L))

    print('Merging sublists:', L[index_left:left_stop_index], 'and',
          L[index_right:right_stop_index]);

    L_tmp = []

    while (index_left < left_stop_index and
           index_right < right_stop_index):
        if L[index_left] < L[index_right]:
           L_tmp.append(L[index_left])
           index_left += 1
        else:
           L_tmp.append(L[index_right])
           index_right += 1

    if index_left < left_stop_index:
           L_tmp.extend(L[index_left : left_stop_index])
    if index_right < right_stop_index:
           L_tmp.extend(L[index_right : right_stop_index])

    L[start_index : right_stop_index] = L_tmp
    print('Merged sublist:', L_tmp, '\n')

def merge_sort(L):
    """
    Sort a list L using the merge sort algorithm.

    (Starter code doesn't fully sort the list.)
    """
    left_start_index = 0
    chunksize = 1  # Start by dividing the list into N sub-lists of 1 element each

    while chunksize < len(L):`enter code here`
        print("\n*** Sorting sublists of size", chunksize)
        print(L)

        while left_start_index + chunksize < len(L):
            merge(L, left_start_index, chunksize)

            # Move to next pair of chunks
            left_start_index += 2 * chunksize

        chunksize= chunksize *2
        print('List is now',L)
```

Hey guys having a lot of difficulty finishing up this code. The def merge portion of the code is fine what im having problems with is the def_merge sort portion.So the code works fine the first time around when sorting sublists of size is 1 but I can't get the code to continue merge sorting after that. I feel as if the problem lies in the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

In the `merge_sort` function, after running the inner while loop, the value of `left_start_index` has changed to be not `0`, hence your code couldn't correctly merge sort beyond the first two elements in the list. After the inner while loop, before `chunksize=chunksize*2`, reset `left_start_index=0` should fix the problem.

```
def merge_sort(L):
    ...
    #outer while loop
    while chunksize < len(L):
        ....
        #inner while loop
        while left_start_index + chunksize < len(L):
            merge(L, left_start_index, chunksize)

            # Move to next pair of chunks
            left_start_index += 2 * chunksize
        #Reset left_start_index to 0
        left_start_index = 0
        chunksize= chunksize *2
        print('List is now',L)
```